# Function looping twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have been working on custom-commands using discord.js obviously for discord, whenever I run my code for some reason it runs it twice the confirmation message is sent twice and the data stored in mongo db is also stored twice I am not been able to find the reason as why that happens
My code:

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    const prefix = "!"
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const data = await customschema.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id, Command: command});
    const cmd = client.commands.get(command) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(command));
    if(data) message.channel.send(data.Response);
    if (cmd) cmd.execute(client, message, args);
});
```

Comment: It appears as the problem is not in the code you have provided us, please provide us with the code that is calling the function.

Comment: I have updated the code please check

Comment: try wraping content in this if statment:

```client.on('message',async message=>{
    if(!message.author.bot){
        //all other code her
    }
})```